# Winform Combo box: Control shifts to end of the text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In a combo box if I select an item whose length is bigger than the size of combo box it self, the focus sets on the combo box and it shows the end of the text. If I tab out now it shows the start of the string.

Value in combo box for both combo boxes: SK_Health_Plan-SELF

Currently It comes as shown below combo box showing the end of the string.

[image]

I want combo box to show as below, when I select an item
[image]

Comment: This is an unmistakable sign that the combo box *needs* to have its width increased. If your design does not allow that, a redesign is required, either to adjust the layout or to change to a different control.

Comment: @CodyGray This solution might work for sometime, but I am filling my combo box dynamically. So if in future I get a bigger value I have to redesign again. Anyways I have set the drop down to auto size according to size of values.